# How to access PageData defined in the parent view in partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to access the PageData defined in the view in the partial view. I am able to access it if I pass the PageData as a model to the Partial view. I don't like this approach as it is not the model for the view.
Partial view will have its own instance of PageData. So is there a way to access the Parent's ViewData?
Here is the sample code...
View Code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    PageData["MyName"] = "Sathi";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<h3>@WebPageContext.Current.Page.PageData.Count()</h3>
<h3>@PageData["MyName"]</h3>
<h3>@WebPageContext.Current.Page.PageData.Count()</h3>
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Partial"); }
Parent view ends here
```

Partial view code

```
This is a partial view
<h3>@PageData["MyName"]</h3><-- Empty
<h3>@WebPageContext.Current.Page.PageData.Count()</h3>
```

Comment: You could pass it via the overload that accepts a `ViewDataDictionary`, but its not clear when you saying the _Partial view will have its own instance of PageData_ - if you do not explicitly pass a model in the `RenderPartial()` method, it will pass the model in the main view anyway